# Getting data from .txt file and sort it into a list

Tags: python

I am trying to get all the data from .txt file looks like this:

```
F 16 D 1 E 4 D 4 F 4 E 8
D 3 D 1 E 4 D 4 A 4 F 8
 
D 3 D 1
```

I want to sort all data in one list:

```
['F', '16', 'D', '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4', 'F', '4', 'E', '8', 'D', '3', 'D',
 '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4', 'A', '4', 'F', '8', 'D', '3', 'D', '1']
```

This is code:

```
    with open("sample2.txt") as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    data = [x.strip() for x in data]
    print(data)
    new_data = list(" ".join(data).replace(" ", ""))
    return new_data
```

But I am getting output:

> ['F', **'1', '6',** 'D', '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4',...]

1, 6 from one element 16 are separated.
It works only if all elements in file consists from only one digit.
What is the way so solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe you want to use: " ".join(data).split(" ") instead of replace?

Comment: What is the output you are *expecting*?

Answer (score 1):

Using just:

```
with open("sample2.txt") as file:
    result = file.read().split()
```

*Should* work...

If you care about memory efficiency, something like:

```
result = []
with open("sample2.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        result.extend(line.split())
```

Alternatively, you can just use regex here:

```
import re
s = """F 16 D 1 E 4 D 4 F 4 E 8
D 3 D 1 E 4 D 4 A 4 F 8

D 3 D 1
"""
result = re.findall(r'\S+', s)
```

more specifically:

```
import re
with open("sample2.txt") as file:
    result = re.findall(r"\S+", file.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` contains each line of your file (without \n) as list element.

This

> ```
> data = list(" ".join(data).replace(" ", ""))
> ```

joins all lines back together with spaces, then you remove all spaces:

So you go from

```
['F 16 D 1 E 4 D 4 F 4 E 8', 'D 3 D 1 E 4 D 4 A 4 F 8', '', 'D 3 D 1']
```

to

```
"F 16 D 1 E 4 D 4 F 4 E 8 D 3 D 1 E 4 D 4 A 4 F 8  D 3 D 1"
```

to

```
"F16D1E4D4F4E8D3D1E4D4A4F8D3D1"
```

then you create a list from this string - which creates each letter as single element.

---

This fixes it:

```
with open("sample2.txt","w")  as f:
    f.write("""F 16 D 1 E 4 D 4 F 4 E 8
D 3 D 1 E 4 D 4 A 4 F 8

D 3 D 1 """)

with open("sample2.txt") as file:
    # read all at once and simply replace the newlines with spaces,
    # then split at spaces
    data = file.read().replace("\n"," ").split()

print(data)
```

Output:

```
['F', '16', 'D', '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4', 'F', '4', 'E', '8', 'D', '3', 'D',
 '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4', 'A', '4', 'F', '8', 'D', '3', 'D', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("sample2.txt") as file:
    result = list(filter(None, file.read().replace("\n", "").split(" ")))

print(result)
```

result:

```
['F', '16', 'D', '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4', 'F', '4', 'E', '8D', '3', 'D', '1', 'E', '4', 'D', '4', 'A', '4', 'F', '8', 'D', '3', 'D', '1']
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem here you did list(" ".join(data).replace(" ", ""))
you can do:

```
with open("sample2.txt") as file:
    data = file.readlines()
data = [x.strip() for x in data]
print(data)
new_data = " ".join(data).replace("  ", "\n")
return new_data
```